# Added an overlay sound using filter_complex, but the overlay sound is 2 seconds behind where it needs to be, how do I adjust this?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm relatively new to ffmpeg, based on examples I found I was able to get this to successfully overlay an audio track over the top of a video with sound and successfully stream to Twitch - however, I need a way to start the audio (audio.ogg) at +2 seconds from where it starts off. I'm not sure how I'd change that here.

```
ffmpeg -re -y -i video.webm \
-filter_complex "amovie=audio.ogg:loop=999,volume=20dB,asetpts=N/SR/TB[aud];[0:a][aud]amix[a]" \
-map 0:v -map '[a]' \
-c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -b:v 3000k -maxrate 3000k \
-bufsize 6000k -pix_fmt yuv420p -g 50 -c:a aac -b:a 256k -shortest \
-f flv "rtmp://fra05.contribute.live-video.net/app/live_xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

How do I start the audio at +2 seconds (audio.ogg) from the beginning?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Feed the audio as a normal input and use stream_loop instead. Use `-ss` to skip first two seconds.

```
ffmpeg -re -y -i video.webm -stream_loop 999 -ss 2 -i audio.ogg \
-filter_complex "[1]volume=20dB[aud];[0:a][aud]amix[a]" \
-map 0:v -map '[a]' \
-c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -b:v 3000k -maxrate 3000k \
-bufsize 6000k -pix_fmt yuv420p -g 50 -c:a aac -b:a 256k -shortest \
-f flv "rtmp://fra05.contribute.live-video.net/app/live_xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but when I run this I get the following errors: 
[Parsed_adelay_1 @ 0x5604a7a7dbc0] Option 'all' not found
[AVFilterGraph @ 0x5604a7a31e40] Error initializing filter 'adelay' with args '2s:all=1'
Error initializing complex filters.
Option not found

Comment: You'll need ffmpeg v4.3 or later.

Comment: Thanks, I upgraded (on another machine and forgot to upgrade) - I got it to run, but if I'm not mistaken, this is the opposite of what I was going for (perhaps I originally attempted it going in the wrong direction and explained it incorrectly) I don't want to delay the audio by 2 seconds, I want to start the audio already at 2 seconds when the video starts. Is there a command for this?

Comment: So you don't want the first two seconds of audio.ogg to be heard? Only at the beginning, or never?

Comment: I don't want the first two seconds of audio.ogg played. So, on an overall timeline it would start the video at 00:00 and the audio at 00:02 at the beginning.

Comment: Only at the beginning, or never?

Comment: Only at the beginning

Comment: Edited command.

Comment: If audio.ogg is known, and fixed, you could clip the first two seconds and add them to the end of the file (eg use Audacity). Don't the buffer and maxrate cause a variable offset between audio.ogg and the stream?

Comment: Encoding parameters such as buffer and maxrate have no interaction with how an input is trimmed or what its sync is.

Comment: @pbhj: Thank you for your idea, but for this use-case we will be combining live streams, so it will be a bit tricky.

Comment: @gyan: Thank you for this update, it works! Marked it as accepted answer